# NullPointerException on context.getPackageName when creating Intent

Tags: java, android

I know this is a question that has been asked before, and I looked through the answers on those and none seemed to be working.

This is the logcat output:

```
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-53419
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046): Process: com.ritvik.weaselyclock, PID: 10046
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:131)
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4006)
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046):    at com.ritvik.utils.HTTPUtils.procResp(HTTPUtils.java:154)
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046):    at com.ritvik.utils.HTTPUtils$1.run(HTTPUtils.java:57)
05-01 16:52:42.748: E/AndroidRuntime(10046):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The error is coming from this line:

```
HTTPUtils.this.startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
```

`HTTPUtils.java:57` is this code:

```
httpUtils.procResp(responseBody);
```

`httpUtils` is the instance of `HTTPUtils.java`

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
This is the rest of the HTTPUtils code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ritvik.weaselyclock.MainActivity;

public class HTTPUtils extends Activity{
    static Context context;
    public static HTTPUtils httpUtils = new HTTPUtils();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(); 
        context = mainActivity.context;
    }
    public static void HTTPPostExec(final String url, final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String responseBody = "";
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response
                            .getEntity());
                } catch (ParseException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Server Response", responseBody);
                httpUtils.procResp(responseBody);
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void HTTPPostExec(final String url, final String msg)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String responseBody = "";
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try 
                {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg", msg));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                }
                catch (ParseException | IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Server Response", responseBody);
                httpUtils.procResp(responseBody);
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void GetExec (final String url, final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String responseBody = "";
                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url + "?" + nameValuePairs.toString());
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try
                {
                    response = Client.execute(httpget);
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Log.d("Server Response", responseBody);
                    httpUtils.procResp(responseBody);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void GetExec (final String url, final String nameValuePairs){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String responseBody = "";
                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url + "?" + nameValuePairs);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try
                {
                    response = Client.execute(httpget);
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Log.d("Server Response", responseBody);
                    httpUtils.procResp(responseBody);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void procResp(String msg) {
        JSONObject JSON = null;
        String type = "";
        try {
            JSON = new JSONObject(msg);
            type = JSON.getString("type");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (type.equals("ru_001")) {
            HTTPUtils.this.startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if (type.equals("ru_002")) {
            Toast.makeText(((MainActivity)context), "Registration successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if (  type.equals("ru_101") || type.equals("ru_102") 
                || type.equals("ru_103") || type.equals("ru_201") 
                || type.equals("ru_202") || type.equals("ru_203") 
                || type.equals("ru_204") || type.equals("ru_205") 
                || type.equals("ru_206") || type.equals("ru_207") 
                || type.equals("ru_208") || type.equals("ru_209") 
                || type.equals("ru_210") || type.equals("ru_211") 
                || type.equals("jr_201") || type.equals("jr_202")
                || type.equals("jr_203") || type.equals("jr_204")
                || type.equals("jr_205") || type.equals("jr_206")
                || type.equals("jr_207") || type.equals("jr_208")
                || type.equals("jr_209") || type.equals("id_201")
                || type.equals("id_202") || type.equals("id_203")
                || type.equals("id_204") || type.equals("id_205")
                || type.equals("id_206") || type.equals("id_207")
                || type.equals("id_208") || type.equals("sm_201")
                || type.equals("sm_202") || type.equals("sm_203")
                || type.equals("sm_204") || type.equals("sm_205")
                || type.equals("sm_206") || type.equals("sm_207")
                || type.equals("sm_208") || type.equals("sm_209")
                || type.equals("sm_210")) {
            try {
                Log.e("Server error:", JSON.getString("error"));
                Toast.makeText(context, "Server error: " + JSON.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if (type.equals("jr_101") || type.equals("jr_102")) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(context, JSON.getString("action"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if (type.equals("jr_301") || type.equals("jr_302")) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You have been " + JSON.getString("action") + "by group" + JSON.getString("group") , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if (type.equals("id_101")) {
            try {
                JSONArray members = JSON.getJSONArray("members");
                JSONUtils.writeJSON("com.ritvik.weaselyclock.MEMBERS", context, members, "members");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Excuse the long if-statement and the bad coding, I know it's horrible...

**UPDATE 2:** I just moved all the code into one activity and it fixed it. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: where are you calling this

Comment: and what is httpUtils is it activity

Comment: `post the relevant part of the code`

Comment: Try to use HTTPUtils.this instead of only this in intent constructor : Intent(HTTPUtils.this, MainActivity.class)

Comment: try this startActivity(new Intent(HTTPUtils.this,MainActivity.class));

Comment: `this` is not yet ready for use. Please post the *entire* `HTPTUtils` class.

Comment: From where you are calling this line `HTTPUtils.this.startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));`

Please post both class From where you are using this line and HTTPUtils itself.

Comment: @HareshChhelana that didn't seem to fix it...

Comment: @apk The code is being called whenever the type is "ru_101".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You are creating the instance of the Activity inside itself. **HTTPUtils** is itself an activity, so don't do this inside it :

```
public static HTTPUtils httpUtils = new HTTPUtils();
```

And try to modify like this to start Activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(HTTPUtils.this, MainActivity.class));
```

Comment: The code from which I'm calling the method is in a separate thread, so the only way I can call it is by making it static. Is that what I should be doing? Forgive me, I'm rather new to this...

Comment: You can use HTTPUtils.this.your_method(); , I think you can, can you ?

Comment: I get this error from eclipse, I'm guessing because the method is being called from a Runnable:

`No enclosing instance of the type HTTPUtils is accessible in scope`